# How to expand button back-ground , while not moving the text?

Tags: html, css

i have button with 8 px height and i want it to become higher when focused , how ever the text starts to jump when i use different height or paddings . How to hold the text still and expand the background ?

html

```
<button class="button">some text</button>
```

css

```
.button {
  font: inherit;

  line-height: 8px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #f0c52e;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;


  border:none;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}

.button:hover,
.button:focus,
.button:active
{
 line-height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Move your button up by `added height / 2`

Comment: It worked , i am grateful.

Answer (score -1):

Make it higher initially and only adjust the background. You can use a gradient coloration for this and change the `background-size` on hover

```css
.button {
  font: inherit;
  line-height: 8px;
  color: #000000;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#f0c52e,#f0c52e) center/100% 8px no-repeat;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 40px;
  transition:0.5s;
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus,
.button:active {
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">some text</button>
```